# Finding the P Value using the Mann Whitney Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The problem is given below:

[image]

Along with the picture of the ranks

[image]

I let the first sample be $X$ and the sum of the ranks which I let $W$ be is 44.  Also, $n_1=6$ and $n_2=5$. Then $n_1 \cdot n_2=30$. Let $U$ denote the number of times each data point in $Y$ is bigger than $X$ and it turns out that $U$ is $23$.

But I am stuck trying to calculate the p-value from this table. I think I need to calculate $2P(U\leq 23)$. But the table cuts off at $23$. But I have a feeling that this is not right either since that would put the p-value above 1.00.

Any help would be great Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours. I tried reading other sources but there is little to no information about this specific test. My book does not have a table for the $U$ statistic either.

Comment: You may have an issue with your ranking. 7.4 < 7.6, yet it is ranked 3, not 2.

Comment: Thanks let me fix that. But how would I calculate the P-value? I think U will still be the same if I switch the rankings around,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly calculated that:
$$
\begin{align}
n_1 &= 6\\
n_2 &= 5\\
\Sigma{R_X} &= 44\\
\end{align}
$$
This implies:
$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma{R_Y} &= 22\\
U_X &= 7\\
U_Y &= 23
\end{align}
$$

The null hypothesis is that the fish are of the same size. This indicates a two-sided test. You know that $P(U = u) u > 30 = 0$. Your confusion may stem from the fact that you are calculating the probability of the U value falling *within* the interval, when, in fact, you need the probability of it falling **outside** the interval.

In this case, you want $2\times(P(U \geq 23)$. You have that in your table; the rest should follow.